# How to save zero as a Double in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my database, I'm keeping track of the distance travelled by users and set an initial value of 0 for everyone. In my code, I am updating this value by getting the old value and adding the new distance to it, then saving that value.

At first, when I retrieve the 0 from the database, it is returned as a Long, which is fine:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Long previousDistance = (Long) dataSnapshot.child("distance").getValue();
    userReference.child("distance").setValue(previousDistance.doubleValue()+distanceTravelled);
 }
```

The problem is that now, the value stored in the database is a Double, so next time the above code is run it will fail with a `ClassCastExcepiton`.

I could probably solve the issue with an if statement, but the easiest solution would be to store the initial 0 as a Double instead. However, I can't make that work. I've tried both of these:

```
myDatabase.child("users").child(lowerCaseUserName).child("distance").setValue(Double.valueOf(0.0));
myDatabase.child("users").child(lowerCaseUserName).child("distance").setValue(0.0);
```

They still get stored as "0" and returned as a Long. Is it possible to store zero as a Double in the database?

Comment: This is a bug or at least flawed design. When you set the data in C#, the runtime knows the exact type of the number (whether it is double, float, long, int, etc.). Firebase is converting the numbers to either Long or Double. Apparently they do it according to whether there are fractional digits, where as it makes more sense to do the casting based on the type alone. So float and double would convert to double, all int types would convert to Long. The current behavior while explainable is weird and causes unnecessary complexity for saving and retrieving floats.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't stored as "0" (String) it is stored as the number 0. In Firebase, it doesn't matter what kind of primitve you are storing, as long as it is a 0 (zero). If you add to an existing value of 0 (zero), 0.01, the result will be: **`0.01`**, which obviously is a Double.

One thing to remember is to get the data from your database in the same wasy you are storing it. If you are setting a value as a Double using this line of code:

```
myDatabase.child("users").child(lowerCaseUserName).child("distance").setValue(0.01);
```

If you want only a 0 (zero), you can only use:

```
myDatabase.child("users").child(lowerCaseUserName).child("distance").setValue(0);
```

And to get it back, you need to use this line of code:

```
double previousDistance = dataSnapshot.child("distance").getValue(Double.class);
```

Comment: What I want is to store 0.0 (double) in the database, but I guess that's not possible.

Comment: You cannot store a value as **`0.0`**. because automatically is converted in **`0`**.

Answer (score 0):

```
double previousDistance = (double) dataSnapshot.child("distance").getValue();
```

And you should put it as normal:

```
myDatabase.child("users").child(lowerCaseUserName).child("distance").setValue(0);
```

Comment: I have tried this, but I will get a ClassCastException, because `.child("distance").setValue(0);` stores it as a Long.

Comment: I think first time you saved as a `Long`. Delete that node from firebase console and try again.

Comment: I did not choose to save is as a `Long`, firebase did so automatically. Anyway, I did what you said and I'm still getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double`

Comment: Did you try `double previousDistance = dataSnapshot.child("distance").getValue(Double.class);` ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is evaluated as a zero no matter if there is a floating point in the number or not so you could either add a close to zero value instead, but with a floating point that have sense. Depending on your required precision this won't hurt.

`...child("distance").setValue(0.0000000001);`

Otherwise storing it as a String and converting back to double everytime you use the value.

I could not find another way of doing that neither, it auto-cast to Long automatically as you said...

Answer (score 0):

Remember that firebase is a JSON tree node based system. You should be using wrappers all along to serialize it to JSON. JSON only supports long as numerical values to firebase, that's why the exception is happening over and over.

It's a good practice implement a method un the form of `SerializeDoubleToString()` and the inverse `DeserializeStringToDouble()`.

Store Doubles as strings; you have a huge impact in the resolution of your numbers, Unity is mainly floating point 32b while firebase 64.